# ASP.Net Impersonation fails when using machine name or IP in url

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, impersonation, windows-identity

Im stuck with the following problem:
I have small MVC application that uses Windows Identity and ASP.Net Impersonation for querying data from MS Project Server. Everything works fine when using localhost. But when accessing site with url that contains either machine name or IP it fails.

Examples:

IIS on local computer:
http://127.0.0.1/myapp/poc - 401 Unauthorized
http://localhost/myapp/poc - OK
http://iisservername/myapp/poc - OK

IIS on test machine via Remote Desktop:
http://127.0.0.1/myapp/poc - 401 Unauthorized
http://localhost/myapp/poc - OK
http://machinename/myapp/poc - 401 Unauthorized
http://machineIP/myapp/poc - 401 Unauthorized

Does anyone have any clue why its acting like this?
Seems like something related to Hosts file or DNS?

Answer (score 0):

> The problem you are running into is called [double hop](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-windows-authentication-and-the-double-hop-issue) issue.

There are many things that can go wrong when you setup the IIS server for double hop authentication.And the things you have to take care is at AD level .To get an understanding,please refer this

- [understanding-kerberos-double-hop](https://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/iis-windows-authentication-and-the-double-hop-issue)
- [configuring-sql-server-kerberos-for-double-hop-authentication](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop/)

Whatever current setup you have done is enough from IIS perpective but to have double hop,you also have to enable some settings at the Active Directory domain level.The steps would be as follows

1 .Find out on what account your application is running

```
 This will be your [application pool identity][3] if you do not have [kernel 
 mode authentication enabled][4].
```

2. Configure SPNs for the above account

   In your case,if you are using the server name only to access the website remotely (http://iisservername/myapp/poc),then your SPN is not necessary.But if you have another name(host or cname entry in the DNS),then you have to use that also for your SPN and register the SPN.

`setspn -A http/iisserver iisserver` if you have kernel mode auth enabled

**please note that setspn is not mandatory for machine account.So ifkernel mode is enabled,step 1 and 2 is not mandatory**

3. Enable Delegation on the IIS application pool identity account

This you have to enable for the application pool identity or the machine account.and this has to be done in the Active Directory*you may need th help of domain administrator) .Refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-desktop-optimization-pack/appv-v4/how-to-configure-the-server-to-be-trusted-for-delegation) for more details .E.g screenshot

[image: enable delgation]

Comment: How would I do this on a regular Windows workgroup member, rather than a domain controller? I use IIS locally to host a dev version of my company's site, and am not worried about configuring any of this stuff on the production server.